# Fuzzy Matching with Postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Right now I am using ts_rank (with ts_vector and ts_query) to search strings for relevance. While this is doing a great job for me so far. I was hoping to work in a bit of fuzzieness into the searching.

As it stands the search is done by a user entering their terms as a string, that I then parse into tokens. These tokens are then compared against a string. What I would like to do is use something similar to a levenshtein in these queries to allow for minor misspellings to be matched as well.

For example if the user typed in rubico instead of rubicon I would still get a match on it (because rubico only has a distance of 1 from rubicon).

Is this possible to do with Postgres' ts_rank functionality, or are there other options to allow for text searches to work with levenstheins?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, but it's not necessarily fun, or fast.

Your best bet for fuzzy matching is "[Soft TFIDF](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C08-1075)" (pdf), probably using [Jaro Winkler](http://pgsimilarity.projects.pgfoundry.org/) similarity. Jaro Winkler is similar to Levenshtein but weights letters more heavily at the beginning of a string. It's available in the pg_similarity extension.

Here's a function I wrote a while ago, which I haven't tested rigorously. It's basically a port from here https://github.com/TeamCohen/secondstring

array_unique() is from the smlar extension. tokenize() just splits on non-alphanums. The table smlar_stats is like this:

```
create table smlar_stats (
  value text unique,
  ndoc int not null
);
```

You'll probably want to create such a table dynamically though.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION soft_tfidf(s text, t text, debug boolean DEFAULT false)
  RETURNS real AS
$BODY$
declare
    s_bag text[] = array_unique( tokenize(s) );
    t_bag text[] = array_unique( tokenize(t) );
    tok text;
    tok_j text;
    sim real = 0.0;
    jw real;
    threshold real = 0.78;
    match_score real;
    match_tok text;
begin

    if debug then raise notice 's_bag: % t_bag: %', s_bag, t_bag; end if;

    foreach tok in array s_bag loop
        if inarray(t_bag, tok) then 
            sim = sim + bag_weight(s_bag, tok) * bag_weight(t_bag, tok);
        else 
            match_score = threshold;
            match_tok = null;
            foreach tok_j in array t_bag loop
                jw = jarowinkler(tok, tok_j);  
                if jw >= match_score then
                    match_tok = tok_j;
                    match_score = jw;   if debug then raise notice 'jw(%,%)=%', tok, tok_j, jw; end if;
                end if;
            end loop;
            if match_tok is not null then
                sim = sim + bag_weight(s_bag, tok) * bag_weight(t_bag, match_tok) * match_score;
            end if;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return sim;

end $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bag_weight(text[], text)
  RETURNS real AS
$BODY$
declare
    w real;
    normalizer real = 0.0;
    token text;
    df real;
    weights real[] = '{}';
begin

    foreach token in array $1 loop
        select ndoc from smlar_stats where value = token into df;
        if df is null then df = 1.0; end if;
        w = log(2) * log(301.1 / df);
        weights = array_append(weights,  w);
        normalizer = normalizer + w*w;
    end loop;

    normalizer = sqrt(normalizer);

    for i in 1..array_length($1, 1) loop
        if $1[i] = $2 then
            return weights[i] / normalizer;
        end if;
    end loop;

end $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
```

Comment: how do we populate smlar_stats table?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching the portion of the string that I wanted to fuzzy search on I instead, concatinated all of the terms into a string, and then ran the difference function (from the fuzzystrmatch module) against it. So it looked something like this.

```
FOR term IN terms LOOP
    term_string := term_string||' '||term;
END LOOP;

score := score + difference(term_string,string_to_compare_against);
```

I did need to set a threshold that needed to be passed by the score to keep from getting to many false positives.