# Compare occurence of chars in PostgreSQL string

Tags: postgresql, varchar, string-manipulation

I have some data like this:

| metaphone | lag |
| --- | --- |
| FLKSW | [null] |
| PPS | FLKSW |
| PPS | PPS |
| PSP | PPS |

And I want to compare the string values in both columns on the folowing condition: they're similar (assign some value, like 1) if they share at least 2 chars. Otherwise, they're not similar.

So in the example, PPS and PSP would be similar.

How can this substring comparison be achieved?

I know one approach would be to extract substrings and manually compare them, but it feels hacky and I don't know the maximum number of chars that can occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fuzzy Matching with Postgresql 9.3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80357/fuzzy-matching-with-postgresql-9-3)

Comment: @mustaccio I'd like to avoid using external extensions.

Comment: In that case you'll end up writing an "internal" extension of your own, in one of the many possible forms. Suit yourself, I guess.

Comment: Metaphone results that share two characters do not necessarily belong to words that are similar in any respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they're similar ... if they share at least 2 chars.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in "intersect" operator or function for strings or [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). You can roll your own function to count overlapping characters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_count_overlapping_char(text, text)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT count(*)::int
FROM (
   SELECT unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL))
   INTERSECT ALL
   SELECT unnest(string_to_array($2, NULL))
   ) sub;
$func$;
```

[`INTERSECT ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) includes duplicate matching characters. To fold duplicates, use just `INTERSECT` instead.

Then your query can be:

```
SELECT *, f_count_overlapping_char(t1.metaphone, t2.metaphone) AS overlap
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
             AND f_count_overlapping_char(t1.metaphone, t2.metaphone) >= 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1d8f9a81c23d32fbeb4d85d6a376fde1)*

But it's expensive and does not scale well with more rows in the table - O(N²). Depending on your actual objective there are various superior alternatives - like trigram similarity provided by the additional module [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).  See:

- [What does the Postgres <-> operator do?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86773/what-does-the-postgres-operator-do/86774#86774)